# How to run the Twisted Matrix Web Server

Tags: python, twisted.web, twisted.internet

I want to run the demo that is part of open source project [JInfinote](https://github.com/sveith/jinfinote/tree/master/demo). The demo server is written using Twisted Matrix library/server. However I have no idea how to run this and if it's standalone server that I need to download in order to run or is it just python or a library and how to configure the whole thing.

When I try to run this in python I'm getting some session exception - as if it was trying to literally execute the code function by function. I would appreciate any help with this.

I am sorry for the level of this question, but I'm not a python programmer and I'm just trying to understand the project JInfinote and this is a blocker.

Comment: I'm afraid that either you're not asking exactly for what you want, or you're missing the point. I've given you an answer, but until you give me something more specific in your question, I'm afraid its the best I can do.

Comment: There's a link to the source code in my question and I was asking about running that specific file. You've already answered my question because the code you gave me is basically the same as in that demo -> now I know I was doing the right thing, but the code is broken (I got error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to run twisted matrix on a web-server, all you have to do is really just run a simple Python Script:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        return "I am request #" + str(self.numberRequests) + "\n"

reactor.listenTCP(80, server.Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

If you listen on port `80` then your server is open to the web. You can learn more about it [from here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).